# Is it okay to keep my fighter fish all by itself in a bowl?

Tags: fish, betta

I got a fighter fish in a bowl today. Only one fighter is put in a bowl. Now I am wondering if it will get lonely. How will it mate? Am I depriving it of a companion?

Answer (score 14):

Betta fish, which is how your fish are more commonly known, are famously aggressive. Males in particular should never be kept with other males -- one *will* kill the other. Females can be kept together in larger groups with care, but pairs or mixed-sex groups won't work. Don't even worry about trying to find it a mate until you're really comfortable keeping them.

Even if they weren't aggressive, the bowl itself is a problem. Bettas really need more water than the bowls they're usually sold with, and there's definitely no room for anything else. They don't need a *huge* tank if they're on their own, but you may have trouble keeping him in such a small space long-term.

I've never personally kept bettas and don't know offhand what the go-to references would be, but [nippyfish.net](http://nippyfish.net/) looks like a good place to learn more. There are sections on [how to house them](http://nippyfish.net/bettas-101/choosing-a-tank/) and how to choose [non-betta tankmates](http://nippyfish.net/bettas-101/tankmates-for-bettas/) down the road, and lots of other information about their care and natural history.

Answer (score 13):

I'm assuming you're referencing the [Siamese fighting fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_fighting_fish) (correct me if I'm wrong.) They tend to be very aggressive, as I'm sure you know, and it is very popular to keep two of them with a separator made of plexiglas or some other acrylic see-through material. I don't think they get "lonely", rather "bored".

As far as breeding them goes, just be careful. You shouldn't have a male and a female together at all times, and preferably not longer than enough to mate. [Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Breed-Betta-Fish)'s a good article on breeding betta fish. Other than that, they prefer to be alone, and no, you're not depriving it of a companion. If you want to keep it from being bored all day, you can put ghost shrimp or snails if you're willing to keep those up as well. :) But that also depends on the size of the environment. I see you're keeping it in a fish bowl, which I'm guessing isn't very big compared to an aquarium, so be careful about how many other animals you introduce into your bowl. Mind that snails waste a lot, so you may have quite a lot of cleaning on your hands if that's what you decide to do.

Comment: I have seen some Siamese fighting fish look very stressed when separated by a see-through material. As for them being "bored", I would dangle things in the water for my guy, and he would follow them around. Most of the time he seemed pretty happy just to be hanging out though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes is is okay to keep them separate. The males are very territorial and will fight so much that one of them could end up dead. So what you're doing is right, keep Siamese fighting fish separate for their own good.

Answer (score 2):

Betta fish shouldn't be housed in a bowl primarily because they just aren't large enough with the recommended minimum tank size being 5 gallons or more for a betta fish to thrive. As for tank mates, it just really depends on the temperament of your individual betta, how large the tank is and making sure there is plenty of hiding places for each to retreat to. A betta however will not get lonely living alone. Here's [a guide](https://bettafish.org/betta-fish-tank-mates/) if you want to read more on the subject and what specific species are best to live together with the betta.

Comment: Siamese fighting fish- also known as bettas, are actually tropical fish and you really need a heater, and a bowl in way to small for a betta fish.. theres heaps of sights you can go on the learn more about bettas, and youtube too.( I would recommend watching 'lifewithpets' youtube channel a long with 'creativepetkeeping' just to name a few.. don't worry I'm still learning too- trust me. Good luck:)